# Unchecked cast when bounding the generic parameter to Class<?>

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have some code that takes an externally provided class name, and needs to construct an instance that implements some interface, lets call it `Foo`.

As part of this process, I'd like to have the following function:

```
private static Class<? extends Foo> fooFromClassName(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return (Class<? extends Foo>) Class.forName(name);
}
```

This obviously results in an unchecked warning, as it is genuinely unsafe - the caller may have requested "java.lang.Long" for all we know.  I'd ultimately like this method to guarantee that if it doesn't throw, then the returned `Class` represents a `Foo` implementation.

My current best solution is this:

```
private static Class<? extends Foo> fooFromClassName(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> impl = Class.forName(name);
    if (Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(impl)) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<? extends Foo> foo = (Class<? extends Foo>) impl;
        return foo;
    } else {
        // Throw something - ClassCastException perhaps.
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?  Is there some way of doing that doesn't require explicit suppression of the warning?

Comment: `Class<? extends Foo>` might be better.

Comment: Was wondering about that originally, but replacing `Class<Foo>` with `Class<? extends Foo>` has exactly the same problem.

Comment: I'm not saying it'll fix anything, but I _am_ saying it's more accurate.

Comment: Changed the examples per @Louis Wasserman suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Class.asSubclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
private static Class<? extends Foo> fooFromClassName(String name) throws ... {
    return Class.forName(name).asSubclass(Foo.class);
}
```

If the requested class isn't a subclass of `Foo` (or `Foo` itself), you'll get a `ClassCastException`. In other words, it does pretty much the same thing your solution does.

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was after.